# Glassfish 3.1 login realm shouldn't prompt for credentials for a specific URL

Tags: authentication, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I have a web application set to prompt for a user name and password at every point of entry. Everything requires basic authentication except for one URL called `showStatus` which is designed to show the status of the application. The `showStatus` URL does not require authentication. The problem is that even when the `showStatus` URL is accessed the password dialog is still shown. I am able to click cancel, or OK and still access the page, but I would like to know how to disable the dialog box for the `showSession` URL.

Here is the contents of `web.xml`:

```
<!-- constraint for restricted pages -->
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>restricted access</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Pages</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>USERS</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- do not require authentication for showStatus URL -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ShowStatus</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/showStatus.action</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<!-- need the login prompt to appear for everything but showStatus -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MYREALM</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>USERS</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Comment: I am still unable to fiqure this out. Can anyone help?

Comment: go back over your own steps,you probably restricted that page also in the configuration. Maybe this link can help you: 
http://javing.blogspot.in/2012/05/here-in-this-video-you-can-see-how-i.html

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have some secured resources on your `showStatus` page. The password dialog is shown when your page is trying to access this resources, as they also served by faces servlet.

You can check what resources are required by monitoring network activity in your browser using firebug or some embedded tools when loading your `showStatus` page. You would see something like this:

[image]

All that is needed is to add this resource URLs to the `<web-resource-collection>` that don't require authentication. Or alternatively you can grant open access to all resources by adding the following pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/faces/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
```